# Drupal7 creating breadcrumb from url of custom page template

Tags: breadcrumbs

I have a template file: called: page--movies--movie-details.tpl.php

which make my url: http://mydomain.com/movie/movie-details/

question is: How can i make my own breadcrumb using that url:
My breadcrumb should like this:

ex: Home > movie > movie details

how can i do that in drupal7?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The [custom breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) module can handle adding breadcrumbs to views.</strike>

The [readme](http://drupalcode.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/README.txt) has information on how to use it.

The recommended module for breadcrumbs is [path breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs).

Comment: Can we please stop recommending that module?
It is abandoned and badly written.
Even their project page points you towards http://drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs.

Comment: My apologies. I haven't actually used that module for a long time, however I have used it a long time ago and it has a recommended release in the last 4 months (even views doesn't release that often). It also has 20000 people using the drupal 7 version. I previously missed the notice on the project page but it probably should say "We are depreciating" not "We're considering depreciating", if that is the case. Along with making that statement a lot more obvious. - Path breadcrumbs does look good though.

Answer (score 0):

This module might be what you seek. I've tried it when I was trying to solve another issue I had with breadcrumbs, but it sounds to do exactly what you need:
http://drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb